# Bootstrap Tooltip is Not Visible when on Fullscreen Mode

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am building a page that has both the normal and fullscreen view. The tooltip works fine on normal view but when on fullscreen view the tooltip is not visible. It is appended before the closing  tag. I have tried adding a z-index with a high number and that does not allow it to be visible either.

Bootstrap v4

I now have a working sample with the same problem replicated.

https://jsfiddle.net/ChidoYo/evj2b53t/2/

```
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Short Table
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th class="text-right">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="view_fullscreen">View Fullscreen</a>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Info here:
            </td>
            <td class="truncate-cell" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Super long text that will be truncated because, well... it's too long">
              Super long text that will be truncated because, well... it's too long
            </td>
            <td>
              Mini Cell
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(() => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  $('#view_fullscreen').on('click', () => {

    let elem = document.getElementById('container');

      if (document.fullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.msFullscreenEnabled ) {

          if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement) {
              if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                  document.exitFullscreen();
              } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                  document.webkitExitFullscreen();
              } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                  document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
              document.msExitFullscreen();
          }

      } else {
          if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
              elem.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
              elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
              elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
              elem.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
        }
    } else {
      console.log('Fullscreen is not supported on your browser.');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: hi did you check this link ?  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5555

Comment: Another suggestion is why don't you expand the container width to the fullscreen mode once you open your browser in fullscreen mode by using javascirpt or detect the full screen mode and then extend the width of the container manually through js or jquery.

Comment: I cant attach the screen shot here but when I tried in fullscreen mode extending the width using inspect element then the tooltip was showing into full screen mode.

Comment: @jimil I did try everything on that Github page with no results.

Comment: @jimil Can you explain exactly what you did on your third comment?

Comment: what I was suggesting is, 1) I did the fullScreen but did not expand the width of container div. (so for example, keep it 700opx or whatever you want) 2) once you are on fullscreen mode then only expand the container div from 700px to whatever the screen size you detect of the device.

Comment: you can do the 2nd step of expanding the container div to a certain size using jquery. By detecting the fullscreen mode and then expand the container div through the javascript side. Now, I did this the fullscreen first and keep it 700px container and then using inspect element I slowly increase the width of container and then it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to this is to use the container option. Make sure to target the parent tag that is used as the container for the fullscreen view.

```
<div id="fullscreen_viewer>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip content here">Tooltip Mouseover</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: '#fullscreen_viewer'
});
```

The following is another approach using "container" as a data attribute:

```
<div id="fullscreen_viewer>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip content here" data-container="#fullscreen_viewer">Tooltip Mouseover</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```